# Error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported in NodeJS/ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, openssl

I am getting this error on server when I try to do jwt.verify() a bearer token in request's Authorize header

```
Error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported
    at Verify.verify (node:internal/crypto/sig:230:24)
    at Object.verify (.../node_modules/jwa/index.js:164:21)
    at Object.jwsVerify [as verify] (.../node_modules/jws/lib/verify-stream.js:54:15)
    at .../node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:127:19
    at getSecret (.../node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
    at module.exports [as verify] (.../node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
    at exports.verify (.../middleware.js:30:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (.../node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (.../node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (.../node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3) {
  library: 'DECODER routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

I've tried using Node v16,v18,v20,
also tried adding --openssl-legacy-provider to my script and export in path,
and also updated my OpenSSL on my M1 machine to latest @3.2.1,
even tried encoding public key to Base64 string but nothing worked.

This is the code:

```
exports.verify = async (req, res, next) => {

    const publicKey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----///-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

    const accessToken = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    
    if(!accessToken) res.sendStatus(403).json({ error: "please provide a token" })
    else {
        try {
            jwt.verify(
                accessToken,
                publicKey,
                { algorithms: ['RS256'] },
                (err, decoded) =>
                  {if(err)
                    {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                    else {
                        resolve(decoded)
                        next()
                    }}
                    
              )
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
}
```

The same code worked before but what changed is a different Auth service so I'm using different publicKey and I'm also getting a token that is signed by different service provider.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On your local env you should have it in on one line and with "": PUBLIC_KEY="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n your key \n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"

And on deployed env you should have it without "": PUBLIC_KEY=-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n your key \n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Also, on public key variable put: `.replace(/\\n/g,"\n")`

This worked for me.